# SLURM+Docker: How to kill docker-created processes using SLURMs scancel

Tags: docker, deep-learning, cluster-computing, slurm, nvidia-docker

We have currently setup a GPU computing cluster with SLURM as a resource manager. As this is a cluster for deep-learning, we manage dependencies by using nvidia-docker images to facilitate different frameworks and CUDA versions.

Our typical use case is to allocate resources with srun and give a command to run nvidia-docker which runs the experiment scripts as per the following:

```
srun --gres=gpu:[num gpus required] nvidia-docker run --rm -u $(id -u):$(id -g) /bin/bash -c [python scripts etc..] &
```

We have discovered an issue where if a slurm job is cancelled using the **scancel** command, the docker process on the node is cancelled, but whatever experiment scripts that were started in the docker still continue. As far as we understand, this is not a fault in SLURM, but rather it is the case that killing a docker process does not kill its spawned processes, they will only be killed with the **docker kill** command. While there might be some way to execute the docker kill command in a SLURM prologue script, we were wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if they have solved it somehow. To summerize, we would like to know:

**How can we ensure that processes started in a nvidia-docker container, which in turn was started by a SLURM SRUN, are killed with SCANCEL?**

Comment: Perhaps you need a higher level of abstration on top of slurm. https://atrio.io/ for example, it is a service that can be useful controlling hpc workloads.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Slurm to use [cgroups](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html) might help here. With `cgroups` enabled, any process belonging to a job is attached to a  `cgroup` and destroyed when the job ends. Destruction is take care of by the kernel so there is no way a regular process can escape that.

Comment: Do you mean to enable process tracking with
`ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup`
in the slurm config? If so, we have this enabled already.